# Convert System Date and time into integer

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime-format

Well I am trying to convert System's current date and time into integer value and then adding it into List.

The code is

```
List<int> _data = new List<int>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            _data.Add((int)Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime()));
            _data.Add((int)Convert.ToInt32(row["S11"]));

        }

        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        chartData = jss.Serialize(_data);
        Response.Write(chartData);
```

I am getting error which says `Invalid cast from "DateTime' to 'Int32'`

I want to convert in such form to make the json which look like`[1386216561000,74]` Here the first member is time in integer format and second is the data which is coming from `sql server`.

Actually what I am trying to do is something similar to this `php` code.
The code is

```
<?php 
// Set the JSON header
header("Content-type: text/json");


$x = time() * 1000;
// The y value is a random number
$y = rand(0, 100);

// Create a PHP array and echo it as JSON
$ret = array($x, $y);
echo json_encode($ret);
?>
```

Comment: php time() function returns a number of seconds - not the DateTime object

Comment: So how do I achieve similar operation in c#?

Comment: One of your problems will be that the example you provided of `1386216561000` exceeds the max value of a C# `int`, which is `2147483647`.

Comment: okk, Still(I can manage with some other data type) if I want to get the similar function like time() in php what is the alternative? I tried but not getting exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your time to [Epoch time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) or to some timespan value from a certain reference point.

Here is the code how you calculate a epoch time:

```
     var timeDiff=DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    var totaltime = timeDiff.TotalMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 3):

The PHP `time()` function returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

So to mimic this functionality in C#, try this:

```
private static double GetUnixEpoch(this DateTime dateTime)
{
    var unixTime = dateTime.ToUniversalTime() - 
        new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    return unixTime.TotalSeconds;
}
```

Usage:

```
var unixTime1 = DateTime.Now.GetUnixEpoch();
```

---

> Note: `GetUnixEpoch` returns a `double`.

---

So your code should read like this:

```
List<double> _data = new List<double>();
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    _data.Add(DateTime.Now.GetUnixEpoch());
    _data.Add((double)Convert.ToDouble(row["S11"]));
}

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
chartData = jss.Serialize(_data);
Response.Write(chartData);
```

Answer (score 1):

DateTime cannot be implicitly converted to int. Consider using ToString() with format. For example...

```
_data.Add((int)Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("HHmmssfff"));
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
 var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
 Console.WriteLine ( Convert.ToInt64((DateTime.UtcNow - epoch).TotalSeconds));;
```

Epoch time starts on 1 Jan 1970, we get the current UTC time and subtract the date Epoch time starts from, we then convert the value to the total number of seconds that has passed since Epoch time.

Additionally, we convert the value to Int64, as Int32 will no longer be able to store the total number of seconds once we reach 2038.

Comment: Epoch time starts on 1 Jan 1970, we get the current UTC time and subtract the date Epoch time starts from and convert the value to the total number of seconds that has passed since Epoch time. Additionally, we convert the value to Int64, as Int32 will no longer be able to store the total number of seconds once we reach 2038.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your date into **UnixTime Stamp** :

Convert **Date Into UnixTimeStamp** :

```
public static double DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(DateTime dateTime)
{
    return (dateTime - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).ToLocalTime()).TotalSeconds;
}
```

Converta **UnitTimeStamp to Date** :

```
public static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime( double unixTimeStamp )
{
    // Unix timestamp is seconds past epoch
    System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0);
    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds( unixTimeStamp ).ToLocalTime();
    return dtDateTime;
}
```